# Can we change the wording on Very Low Quality Answer Flag

Tags: discussion, flags

The current wording:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is
>   unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

The wording of this flag leads me and I think a great many others to thing that **content problems** means that when the answer is very obviously wrong or more rant than answer it is the correct flag to use.

However across SE the mods disagree and decline this flag.

Could we reword this flag to be more specific like:

> This answer is unintelligible or otherwise unreadable and is
>   unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be
>   removed.

Answer (score 2):

I am a mod, and I use and support the usage of this flag for answers with very bad formatting and also for the ones which are very low quality in terms of content (like, link-only answers, rants, etc).

So, the current wording is very appropriate for the way it is intended to be used. Also, your rewording suggestion completely changes the intention of the flag, and limits it to **only** badly formatted answers.

Comment: What are you a mod on? Your profile doesn't say

Comment: @user00001 https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dawny33 I am open to a wording change that clarifies what is a severe content problem is then.

Comment: @caird it's visible in the [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/6444670/dawny33?tab=accounts), not part of the per-site profiles due to the "low" reputation. Worth starting a feature request asking to place accounts with diamond on top, regardless of reputation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard on the app when looking at the sites it doesn't show

Comment: @caird android app I guess? Yeah, it simply does not show diamonds on user's sites list, it's just bad design.

Comment: @ShadowWizard iOS app

Comment: The suggested wording is much closer to how these flags seem to be handled _on Stack Overflow_. I think that is where the disconnect is.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Because on SO on topic is much more black and white than on some of the more subjective sites, like most of the SE sites.  SO and SE are seperated enough now I hope we can find a way to communicate the proper intent of this flag on SE.

Comment: I'm very much in favor of the flag being handled on SO as you describe, but the current state is otherwise.